# Linear layout overdraw preventing click event to the views beneath it but allows scroll event

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a linear layout faded layout over a scrollview, for achieving a disabled look and feel.
But that layout should block all the click events but allows scroll option to drag the layout beneath this faded layout.

I tried with following code,

```
layer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                isMoveAction = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(!isMoveAction){
                    return true;
                }
                break;                  
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                isMoveAction = true;
                return false;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but didnt work as expected .
Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance,
JRH

Answer (score 2):

I got one solution for this. Not sure whether this is the best solution for this,

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

private boolean isOffLine;

public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}
```

onInterceptTouchEvent will disable all the click events to this child views.
Hope this is fine.

Thanks

JRH

Comment: thanks, it help me get rid of when I was working with Custom LinearLayout which actually contain some of it child view in scroll view. So if I put click listener for child view then it skip touch of parent. so instead of onTouch I used onInterceptTouchEvent..Thanks